# Google Sheets v4 API calls using Node.js and the result is inconsistent

Tags: node.js, google-sheets, oauth-2.0, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to extract a short data from Google Sheet, the flow is as follow;

- Authorizing the user (access type: offline)
- Storing/caching the token per the oAuth2 flow.
- Loading the cached token and use it to extract the data.

But once I uploaded on the server, the returned result become inconsistent.

I don't know what causing it because most of the time it returns the right data,  and it works perfectly on my local.

Error Message;

```
Google sheet API read: Error: The request is missing a valid API key.
```

Server Information: Google App Engine, trial version;

```
runtime: nodejs
env: flex
```

The node.js code is below;

```
getUser(id) {

  this.sheets.spreadsheets.values.get({
    auth: this.oauth2Client,
    spreadsheetId: id,
    range: 'Sheet1!A1:E'
  }, (err, response) => {

    if(err) {

      this.reject({
        status: 0,
        message: "Google sheet API read: " + err
      });
      return;
    }

    // The rest is omitted.

  })
}
```

You can try the test request here (I haven't added any security measure for debugging purposes);

https://deep-contact-179901.appspot.com/v1/google/users

Answer (score 0):

Based from this [thread](https://reformatcode.com/code/http/http-google-sheets-api-v4-how-to-access-without-oauth-20), all Google APIs require that you create a project on [Google Developer Console](https://console.developers.google.com/) and identify yourself and your application, even to access public data. Go to Google Developer Console and create a public api key. Remember to activate the Google Sheets API. Then just add `key=[YourKey]` as a parameter on your request.

> ```
> Google sheet API read: Error: The request is missing a valid API key.
> ```
>
> Means that you have not identified yourself to Google. In 2015 Google Start to require that we identify ourselves you cant just use a Google API without telling google who you are. You do that by creating a project on [Google developer console](https://console.developers.google.com/). Create an API key and use that API key in all of your requests. This only works with Public data.
>
> Note: With private user data you would need to use OAuth and use either access_token=your token or set the header
>
> An access token is not the same as a API Key.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Migrated it to VM Instance working as expected, it was the Google App fault